# Parsing dataframe based on another dataframe? (cell by cell?)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'clinDF' that I have to update based on another one, 'parsingDF', through R. Let's say:

```
#clinDF
    P1  P2  P3  P4
A   M   F   M   M
B   H   M   L   M
C   3   4   1   0

#parsingDF
    feat  var  col
[1] A     M    #B3E2CD
[2] A     F    #E41A1C
[3] B     H    #A6CEE3
[4] B     M    #FCCDE5
[5] B     L    #8DD3C7
[6] C     0    #BC80BD
[7] C     1    #A6CEE3
[8] C     3    #B3E2CD
[9] C     4    #E41A1C
```

My objective is to parse `clinDF` such that I get the corresponding `col`:

```
#out:
    P1        P2        P3        P4
A   #B3E2CD   #E41A1C   #B3E2CD   #B3E2CD
B   #A6CEE3   #FCCDE5   #8DD3C7   #FCCDE5
C   #B3E2CD   #E41A1C   #A6CEE3   #BC80BD
```

Ideally, I want the code to be as general as possible and **not changing all** in `clinDF` by setting `clinDF[clinDF==3]=#B3E2CD`. Is there a better way to do this than using two `for` loops, to read row by row and column by column?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually, now that I see it they are both matrices, but working with data.frame would be the same I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution ~

```
library(Reshape)
library(Reshape2)
    Table1=melt(as.matrix(clinDF) )
    Table1=merge(Table1,parsingDF,by.x=c('X1','value'),by.y=c('feat','var'),all.x=T)
    dcast(Table1, X1~X2, value.var="col")  

   X1   P1      P2      P3      P4
1  A #B3E2CD #E41A1C #B3E2CD #B3E2CD
2  B #A6CEE3 #FCCDE5 #8DD3C7 #FCCDE5
3  C #B3E2CD #E41A1C #A6CEE3 #BC80BD
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using functions from `tidyverse`. `clinDF2` would be the final output.

```
# Create example dataframes
clinDF <- read.table(text = "    P1  P2  P3  P4
A   M   F   M   M
                     B   H   M   L   M
                     C   3   4   1   0",
                     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

parsingDF <- read.table(text = "feat  var  col
A     M    '#B3E2CD'
A     F    '#E41A1C'
B     H    '#A6CEE3'
B     M    '#FCCDE5'
B     L    '#8DD3C7'
C     0    '#BC80BD'
C     1    '#A6CEE3'
C     3    '#B3E2CD'
C     4    '#E41A1C'",
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Process the data
clinDF2 <- clinDF %>%
  rownames_to_column("feat") %>%
  gather(Group, var, -feat) %>%
  left_join(parsingDF, by = c("feat", "var")) %>%
  select(-var) %>%
  spread(Group, col) %>%
  remove_rownames() %>% 
  column_to_rownames("feat")
```

Comment: You can include everything in the pipe If you do `... %>% spread(Group, col) %>% remove_rownames() %>% column_to_rownames('feat')`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for the update. I will edit my answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `data.table`.  As both the datasets are matrices, `melt` the 'clinDF' to 'long' format, convert to `data.table` (`setDT/as.data.table`), join `on` the 'feat/var' 'Var1/value' columns of the dataset and reshape it back to 'wide' format with `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(clinDF)
setDT(dM)
acast(as.data.table(parsingDF)[dM, on = .(feat = Var1, var = value)],
                feat ~ Var2, value.var = 'col')
#        P1        P2        P3        P4       
#A "#B3E2CD" "#E41A1C" "#B3E2CD" "#B3E2CD"
#B "#A6CEE3" "#FCCDE5" "#8DD3C7" "#FCCDE5"
#C "#B3E2CD" "#E41A1C" "#A6CEE3" "#BC80BD"
```